# Are the axioms of a topological space superfluous?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, definition, topological-vector-spaces

A topology on a set $X$ is a family $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $X$, which are open sets and satisfy:

(1) $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{T}$.

(2) Any union of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

(3) Any finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

An open set $\mathcal{T}$ is defined as a set such that for every $x \in \mathcal{T}$ there is some open interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subseteq \mathcal{T}$, with $\epsilon > 0$.

Then by the definition of an open set it is not difficult to argue that:

(4) The union of any family of open sets is open.

(5) Any finite intersection of open sets is open.

Does this mean that conditions (2) and (3) just follows from the fact $\mathcal{T}$ is an open set?

Furthermore, isn't it an assumption of set theory that $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set and thus automatically $\emptyset \in X$?

Comment: What? Empty set is actually superfluous, but you seem to think almost everything is superfluos...

Comment: $\mathcal{T}$ is not an open set: Open sets are *members* of the topology $\mathcal{T}$, not the topology itself. Remember that a topology is a special collection of subsets of $X$. Also, $\emptyset \subseteq X$ is always true, but $\emptyset \in X$ is not.

Comment: Your definition of an open set is valid only for the real line. There are other topological spaces.

Comment: Other people have explained your mistakes. I'll just point out that it *is* redundant to say $\emptyset\in\mathcal T$, because this follows as a special case of axiom 2. Mathematicians almost always say it anyway.

Comment: One thing that might interest you is the following construction.  Let $X=\{p, q\}$ and let $\mathcal T = \{ \emptyset, \{p\}, \{p, q\}\}$.  Then $\mathcal T$ is a topology on $X$.  It satisfies all the axioms, but it is utterly devoid of anything like $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. This is not a trick; $X$ here is a genuine topological space, a simple but important example called the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space).

Comment: @MJD thanks. It is good to see some examples, because topology (and abstract maths) is definitely outside of my comfort zone (but I want to learn more about it).

Comment: @MJD: In fact, all of condition (1) follows from (2) and (3) by convention regarding union/intersection of an empty family of subsets of a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic is backwards here. The three axioms you give are the axioms defining a general topological space. When you start talking about open intervals, you're talking about the set $\mathbf{R}$ (open intervals don't make sense in a general set). You're specifying a collection of sets of $\mathbf{R}$ that you want to be the opens of a topology, and because, as you observe, the union of any family of such sets, and any finite intersection of such sets, is again such a set, the collection is indeed a topology (well, once you also verify that $\mathbf{R}$ itself and $\emptyset$ satisfy the condition you give involving open intervals).

Answer (score 3):

1. Not every topological space has a notion where $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ makes sense.
2. $\cal T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, whereas $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is a subset of $X$. Membership is not inclusion, usually.
3. $\varnothing$ is a subset of every set, but it's not necessarily a member of every set.
4. By definition, the (4) and (2); and (5) and (3) are equivalent. You just reformulated the statement. The reason is that the elements of $\cal T$ are *defined* as open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is wrong. The elements of $\mathcal{T}$ *are* the open sets *by definition.* It makes no sense to speak of the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ in an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 1):

Without a topology, an open set *cannot* be defined. It is important that this notion is well understood. You were talking about $\mathbb{R}^1$ - so define the usual topology $T_\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Then, $(x+\epsilon,x-\epsilon)$ can be define as an open set, i.e., an element of $T_\mathbb{R}$.

The elements of $\mathcal{T}$ are open sets, however, it does not make sense to say that "conditions (2) and (3) just follows from the fact $\mathcal{T}$ is an open set?", the reason being that *an open set cannot be defined without first defining a topology.*

Also, the empty set is not an element of any set - however, by the definition of a topology, it **has** to be an element of $\mathcal{T}$.